# mysql 8, workbench (8.0.11) crashes when creating stored procedure with input parameters

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to Mysql and Workbench after using MSSQL for a long time.

I was creating stored procedures using the following route:
Right click on Stored Procedures (within the relevant database)
"Create Stored Procedure"

After successfully creating about 10 procedures I hit a problem.
When I pressed the Apply button the Workbench crashed.
I repeated the behaviour on a second machine. Tested on Windows 10 [Version 10.0.15063] and then on Windows Server 2016. In both cases the database was on the local machine.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `updatePeopleTest1` (

Forename1 varchar(255)
)
begin
update tblpeople set forename=Forename1
where uniqueid=1238;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I noticed I had not included an IN before the parameter.
This solved the problem.

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) the IN parameter is optional.

> Each parameter is an IN parameter by default. To specify otherwise for
>   a parameter, use the keyword OUT or INOUT before the parameter name.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `updatePeopleTest1` (

IN Forename1 varchar(255)
)
begin
update tblpeople set forename=Forename1
where uniqueid=26958;

end;
```

Comment: That was a bug which is already fixed. Very soon version 8.0.12 of MySQL Workbench is released where this problem is no longer present.